# Array element retrieval from passed parameter in a PHP file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am calling a PHP file using http.post, passing a json object in the process.
I have managed to retrieve the object from within the PHP and have attached the dump below. All I now need is to retrieve 'name', 'email' and 'message' strings from the array but am finding this difficult as not used to PHP.

```
            Connected successfully<pre>string(2467) "Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [$viewValue] => testing one two
                        [$modelValue] => testing one two
                        [$validators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$asyncValidators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$parsers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$formatters] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )

                        [$viewChangeListeners] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$untouched] => 
                        [$touched] => 1
                        [$pristine] => 
                        [$dirty] => 1
                        [$valid] => 1
                        [$invalid] => 
                        [$error] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$name] => fullName
                        [$options] => 
                    )

                [email] => Array
                    (
                        [$viewValue] => test@onetwo.com
                        [$modelValue] => test@onetwo.com
                        [$validators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$asyncValidators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$parsers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$formatters] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )

                        [$viewChangeListeners] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$untouched] => 
                        [$touched] => 1
                        [$pristine] => 
                        [$dirty] => 1
                        [$valid] => 1
                        [$invalid] => 
                        [$error] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$name] => email
                        [$options] => 
                    )

                [message] => Array
                    (
                        [$viewValue] => testing testing
                        [$modelValue] => testing testing
                        [$validators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$asyncValidators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$parsers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$formatters] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )

                        [$viewChangeListeners] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$untouched] => 
                        [$touched] => 1
                        [$pristine] => 
                        [$dirty] => 1
                        [$valid] => 1
                        [$invalid] => 
                        [$error] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$name] => message
                        [$options] => 
                    )

            )
            "
            <br /><br />Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [$viewValue] => testing one two
                        [$modelValue] => testing one two
                        [$validators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$asyncValidators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$parsers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$formatters] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )

                        [$viewChangeListeners] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$untouched] => 
                        [$touched] => 1
                        [$pristine] => 
                        [$dirty] => 1
                        [$valid] => 1
                        [$invalid] => 
                        [$error] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$name] => fullName
                        [$options] => 
                    )

                [email] => Array
                    (
                        [$viewValue] => test@onetwo.com
                        [$modelValue] => test@onetwo.com
                        [$validators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$asyncValidators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$parsers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$formatters] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )

                        [$viewChangeListeners] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$untouched] => 
                        [$touched] => 1
                        [$pristine] => 
                        [$dirty] => 1
                        [$valid] => 1
                        [$invalid] => 
                        [$error] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$name] => email
                        [$options] => 
                    )

                [message] => Array
                    (
                        [$viewValue] => testing testing
                        [$modelValue] => testing testing
                        [$validators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$asyncValidators] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$parsers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$formatters] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )

                        [$viewChangeListeners] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$untouched] => 
                        [$touched] => 1
                        [$pristine] => 
                        [$dirty] => 1
                        [$valid] => 1
                        [$invalid] => 
                        [$error] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [$name] => message
                        [$options] => 
                    )

            )
            </pre>
```

The PHP code which retrieves the object in the first place is as follows:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$text = print_r($data,true);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($text);
echo "<br /><br />";
print_r($text);
echo "</pre>";
```

How can I access the 'name', 'email' and 'message' strings please?

Comment: `$data['name']`, `$data['message']`, `$data['email']`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your array isnt a valid one... it should be something like this:

BTW remove the $ from inside the arrays.

```
$newarr = Array(
  "name" => Array(
    "first_name" => "Alex",
    "last_name" => "Gonzalez"
     ),
  "email" => Array(),
  "other_sub_array" => Array()
);
```

Now to get let say the first name, since it is a subarray (so an array inside another array).

```
echo $newarr['name']['first_name'];
// Result: Alex
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

I didn't mean not valid, it is a bad practice to use an array like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The array was generated in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is valid unlike the other answer supposes. I assume that you are using some framework that generates the relatively strange json you're reading in. But to the point you can get them via:

```
//note I used single quotes so that the dollar sign isn't evaluated to a php variable
$data['name']['$modelValue'];
$data['message']['$modelValue'];
$data['email']['$modelValue'];
```

Comment: Great -  thanks very much. I stuck with the camel case rather than snake case for now but have finally managed to update my db.